# Is it possible to define types based on an object?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it's possible to take an object literal and derive types from it. ie.

```
const inputs = [
  {
    name: "announcements",
    type: "list",
    subFields: [
      {
        name: "copy",
        type: "string",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
      {
        name: "buttonLabel",
        type: "string",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
      {
        name: "buttonUrl",
        type: "url",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Could I have it automatically inferred as:

```
interface Announcements {
  copy: string;
  buttonLabel: string;
  buttonUrl: string;
}
type AnnouncementList = Announcements[];
```

This would be nice because me definitions need to be defined a particular way and rather than redefining them (and possibly making a mistake) it's much easier if inferred.

Comment: This inference doesn't match your exemple. But you can infer the type with `typeof`.

Comment: There are some interesting projects out there (eg json2ts.com, jvilk.com/MakeTypes, app.quicktype.io) which seem to get some json samples and generate the equivalent typescript types/interface. But I am not sure on how accurate they can be. For example a type like this `{prop: "foo" | "bar"}` maybe interpreted to `{prop: string}`

Comment: Ah it would be sweet to be able to do type AnnouncementList = FromObject<inputs>; Thanks for the list of websites, those might be helpful on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type manipulation in TypeScript does allow us to create types based on other types like the one you showed in your question. Since the keys of `Announcements` are string literals in the object, we need to use `as const` to preserve the narrowed string literal types.

```
const inputs = [
  {
    name: "announcements",
    type: "list",
    subFields: [
      {
        name: "copy",
        type: "string",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
      {
        name: "buttonLabel",
        type: "string",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
      {
        name: "buttonUrl",
        type: "url",
        defaultValue: "",
      },
    ],
  },
] as const
```

Now we can build a new type based on the type of `inputs`.

```
type Announcements = {
  [K in typeof inputs[0]["subFields"][number]["name"]]: string
}

// type Announcements = {
//     copy: string;
//     buttonLabel: string;
//     buttonUrl: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=5&pln=25&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVyhGBeGBtAUDGAb3wJjAEMBbAUwC4YAicsMEZMYamsNBgGhIEoAT0R1GAGzjR%20gmBGQAjAGJxqEgCYR6eUqWJ69FGvQahEw2YdIixp6ACcEAcyvWYG6gDNyyCVAA1cglkcQY3PQBfAWsDd2MwxVQocAAZckV1CMNbMMcXbL1PHz9A4NDTQphouQI46wTTJKgUsABVBwkqoVEw5E7uj29ffyCQsKqavQBdGOqBaZhydFBIKFxcXJgAQRY2Di5qHnQsOOwAaXgwGFyQLyuUNGwABmnsBgUVNU0IBjewZCUTION4MBJ-ab0fJgZy4SK4AD0CJuvR2e3YnG4aEwRERyL05mEUKgThhAG48YZmq10pkJMTSc4KUiqclwB16fISS5mcjIkA)

Comment: This made a lot of sense, thank you! The problem is I think typeof wouldn't work in a situation where the structure is recursive. I outlined a bit more structure here as an example: https://shorturl.at/KNPX2. The tricky parse is the subfields will result in something like